# scroll down to the next youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, youtube

I have a Wordpress page with Youtube videos. When the video is finished, I want to make it scroll to the next div with the class no problem. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="embed-container"><iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xcC3UQl3V-U?&autohide=0&modestbranding=1&controls=2&rel=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

//somthing on html and in the next //

<div class="embed-container"><iframe id="playerxcC3UQl3V-U" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xcC3UQl3V-U?&autohide=0&modestbranding=1&controls=2&rel=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

.... and about 10 or 20 posts like this pro page
```

It works OK when I tried a test using `alert('done');`, but I don't want it to alert something. I want it to scroll to the next div with the class. I found a lot of code from jQuery, but I can not get it to work. Maybe for someone it is easy, but I am new in the Javascript world. Here is my Javascript:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
   if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First figure out the y position of the element you want to scroll to and then use window.scrollTo:

```
  var y = document.getElementById('playerxcC3UQl3V').getBoundingClientRect().y 
    + window.scrollY
  window.scrollTo(0, y);
```

Comment: thets work but thets scroll at the first yotuube video only at the fist video but thet what  the code must to do is to scroll to the next  iframe or div id  for example i lock a  the post 4 in the page and when finished to scroll to the post number 5      somthing like scroll to next post  class from thet div wher i am